# Mouse Button Order Gets Reset after Restart

Tags: mouse, kde, kde5

I using KDE 5.13 on KDE Neon. I use Left-handed mouse. But When I restart the computer, It goes back to Right-handed even if Settings still shows Left handed.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution as follows:

1. First, create shell script with following line:

   xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"

You can find the documentation on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

2. Then add it to Autostart program as follows and make sure You have selected run on as **Before session startup**

[image]